# Does empty constructor is created although another constructor was explicitly written?

Tags: java, kotlin, inheritance, constructor, default-constructor

I'm new in Kotlin (have some experience with Java).
In java, if we writing at least one constructor so the compile **won't build** any empty constructor. Empty constructor will be build only if we didn't write a constructor.
I know that in Kotlin, compiler also working the same as in Java.
I wrote in Kotlin a super class (with the name *Animal*) with a constructor with one parameter.
In addition i wrote a sub class for *Animal*, and the subclass calls an empty constructor of *Animal*. I can't understand why compiler doesn't inform me that it is a compile error since *Animal* class doesn't have an empty constructor to be called.
My code:

```
    open class Animal (val str:String = "sav")
{
    open var fff:String = ""
    open var image = ""
    open val food =""
    open val habitat =""
    var hunger = 10

     open fun makeNoise()
    {
        println("The animal is making noise")
    }
}

class Hippo ( var strrr:Int = 7) : Animal()
{
    override var image = "hippo.jpg"
    override var food = "grass"
    override val habitat = "water"



    override fun makeNoise()
    {
        println("Grunt! Grunt!")
    }
}
```

> class Hippo ( var strrr:Int = 7) : Animal()> isn't a problem?

Comment: @Nicolas,who is the primary constructor? not the one with the **val str:String = "sav"

Comment: Sorry, I deleted the comment, it wasn't true. The problem here is that your constructor has a default value, hence, there IS an empty constructor.

Comment: @Nicolas, Thanks i understand the problem. But only to be accurate (for my knowledge), it doesn't really an empty constructor, it has a constructor with a default parameter. Am i right?

Comment: If I recall, Kotlin will generate a synthetic constructor for the case where there is no argument given. That constructor won't be visible from Java. So it's not really an empty constructor, or the absence of one, more like something in between.

Comment: @Nicolas, i understand. Thanks!!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#constructors) states:

> On the JVM, if all of the parameters of the primary constructor have default values, the compiler will generate an additional parameterless constructor which will use the default values.

By the way, this constructor will be visible from Java too.

Comment: @MC Emperor, Sorry. i will delete my comment

Comment: @Михаил Нафталь, You have mentioned the JVM. Does it mean that it won't work when i try to compile it on Android Studio?

Comment: Don't know for sure (especially in terms of objects in generated bytecode), but since official [Kotlin playground for Android](https://developer.android.com/training/kotlinplayground) uses JVM target, this should work the same way.